# Linux find reencode all files to subdirectory

Tags: linux, encoding, find, iconv

I'm trying to reencode all files in a directory and put the results in a subdirectory.
I'm using

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 {} >  reencoded/{} \;
```

But the filename does not replace the second occurrence of '{}', there is a result in reencoded/{} instead.

Comment: From `man find`: ``Only one instance of  `{}' is  allowed  within the command.``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the command inside a call to `sh -c`, which can then reference the `{}` as `$0`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir sh -c 'iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 "$0" >  reencoded/"$0"' {} \;
```